# Android app unable to write in my gallery

Tags: android

My all should select pic from my gallery using uploadlicence button then insert it to webserver using insert button.

selecting the pic has no problem. the below error appears when clicking on insert. (I checked the selecting process wit toast and it is working)

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0042.JPG: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied).
```

I've added the needed permissions to my ManiFest File as below but the problem stil exist.

Edit: (Solved): in Marchmellow you need to check the permissions programitcally and grant it for user, I made the below:

```
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}

then add the function before the operation you want:

verifyStoragePermissions(YourActivity.this);

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.rentacar.rentacar">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
```

My Code:

```
UploadLicence.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            // Start the Intent
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
        }
    });

InsertRentCar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if (imgPath != null && !imgPath.isEmpty()) {

               // Convert image to String using Base64
               encodeImagetoString();
               // When Image is not selected from Gallery
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(
                       getApplicationContext(),
                       "You must select image from gallery before you try to upload",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       }
   });

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            // Get the Image's file name
            String fileNameSegments[] = imgPath.split("/");
            fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
            // Put file name in Async Http Post Param which will used in Php web app
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), imgPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}

 public void encodeImagetoString() {new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 3;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath,
                options);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        // Encode Image to String
        encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        // Put converted Image string into Async Http Post param
        // Trigger Image upload
        triggerImageUpload();
    }
}.execute(null, null, null);

}

public void triggerImageUpload() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), encodedString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: If you are testing on a device running on marshmallow, you need Runtime Permissions. You can check this out: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @PrerakSola No. You need it only if you built your app with targetSdk 23 in first place

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: If it's being tested on marshmallow, the targetSdk has to be 23.

Comment: Many thanks Guys, that was my problem, I granted real time permissions when Insert button is clicked

Comment: @PrerakSola Again - your  statament `If you are testing on a device running on marshmallow, you need Runtime Permissions.` is wrong in its current form as it suggest you must have Runtime Permission support when running on M, while you can test on marshmallow w/o targetSdk 23 and w/o Runtime Permissions. Got the difference?